# Pierdo el valor de una respuesta de ajax, para otra función

Tags: javascript, ajax

en mi respuesta de ajax obtengo comisiones y ejecuto la siguiente función para que btn tenga el parámetro de comisiones.

btn(comisiones);

Aquí tengo el valor de comisiones que almacena un arreglo y se imprime bien.

Pero al querer ocupar la misma función lineas mas abajose pierde lo que tenia guardado en comisiones. Mi pregunta es como puedo guardar ese valor en esa función para que no pierda ese arreglo.

```js
function btn(comisiones) {
    console.log('ciclado',comisiones);
    const lista = comisiones
    console.log('lista',lista);
}
```

Me aparece como undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de que entre a una función, guárdala en una variable global. Puedes hacerlo con un push.

```
datosGuardar = []; //Variable global, fuera de la función, al inicio del código
datosGuardar.push(comisiones);
console.log(datosGuardar);
```

Entonces lo tendrás guardado en una variable global donde puedes acceder a él en cualquier instancia.

Comment: Me salvaste, gracias !

Comment: Con mucho gusto., happy coding!